# Atlassian Bamboo Could not resolve dependencies with classifier

Tags: maven, bamboo

I have a multimodule maven project that works pretty fine.
One of the modules has been slightly tweaked to produce different artifacts, using the maven-jar-plugin and the maven-install-plugin, combined.

When I run `mvn install` from root, all the modules are built and stored in my local repository, and the modules that include one of these artifacts is built successfully.

Now, I linked the source code to Bamboo, creating different tasks, to compile, test, package and deploy.
The problem is that when I run the "install" task, that is just a simple `mvn clean install -Pmy-profile -U` it fails with the following message:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project my-group:artifact:jar:vers: Failure to find my-group:another-artifact:jar:classifier:vers in http://my-nexus/repository/maven-public/`

The strange thing is that the required artifact is present in the local repository, but it looks like bamboo's not even trying to use it.

I tried with both local repository isolation enabled and disabled, but nothing changes.

I really don't know what to do right now, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `maven clean deploy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was with the `classifier` tag of the pom, but let's explain better the actual project structure:

the parent pom has (among others) 2 children projects, like this:

```
myApp 
+ artifact1 
+ artifact2
```

the `artifact1`, through the `maven-jar-plugin` generates several packages, because for legacy reasons we need to exclude some class from each jar. Therefore, the result is

```
artifact1-legacy.jar
artifact1.jar
```

where `legacy` and `complete` are defined via the `classifier` element.

And now the problem: `artifact2` depends on artifact1-legacy, and it's declared as dependency with the classifier tag, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <classifier>legacy</classifier>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Although this configuration works perfectly via command line, ide, etc, it doesn't work with Atlassian Bamboo.

Luckily, the dependency is provided, this means that it's included effectively somewhere else, so I fixed it by removing the `classifier` tag, like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And this fixed my problem.
Hope this will help someone else with a similar issue.